# For-in loops order in dart

Tags: dart, for-in-loop

If I use `for-in` loop in dart on some `List`, are the iterations guaranteed to be in the correct order? e.g. Does the following code

```
List bars = getSomeListOfBars();

for(bar in bars){
    foo(bar);
}
```

in the exact same way as the following?

```
List bars = getSomeListOfBars();

for(int i=0;i<bars.length;i++){
    foo(bar[i]);
}
```

I have not found `dart` specific explanation anywhere, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `for(x in y)` with a collection that guarantees the iteration order, then `for(x in y)` is guaranteed to iterate in this order. If the collection itself doesn't guarantee the order, then of course `for(x in y)` doesn't as well.

Comment: Exactly correct, and the `List` class guarantees iteration in increasing index order.

Comment: Is this from DLS?

Comment: What is DLS? . .

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. I mean Dart Language Specification.

Comment: It's just syntactic sugar for https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-core/Iterable-class.html "The iterators of the same iterable should provide the same values in the same order"